# insert dynamic columns in SQL database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-insert

I'm creating an application that reads data from a PLC and writes it into a database.

In my GUI the user can select which data he wants to log into the database, but I'm wondering how to solve this.

sometimes the user wants to log only one item in the database :

```
INSERT INTO myTabel (name_data1) VALUES ("123")
```

but other times I must be able to choose more data :

```
INSERT INTO myTabel (name_data1, name_data2, name_data3) VALUES ("123", "456", "789")
```

how would I code this? The column names name_data1, name_data2, name_data3, ... in my database should be able to change according to which data is chosen
for this purpose I use a list of 2 strings

```
["name_data1", "123"],
["name_data2", "456"],
["name_data3", "789"]
```

so the problem also is that I do not know how the table will look like at the moment I insert the data, it all depends on which data the user chooses to be inserted into the database

If I'm correct this is called creating dynamic columns, but I do not seem to find much info on this subject.

Comment: You would perform three inserts.

Comment: You don't use multiple columns. You use a single column, generate an identifier for the batch, and perform N inserts using that batch ID where N is the number of items in your batch.

Comment: How many options/columns can select the user?, 10 options, 100 options?. If the case it's a fix number, use a single Insert and pass only the according column values, and the rest in NULL.

Answer (score 0):

yo can always use all the columns and if a value is not provided you pass null

like

```
INSERT INTO myTabel (name_data1, name_data2, name_data3) VALUES ("123", null, "789")
```

but if you want to use dynamic sql which is not always recommended would look like this :

```
DECLARE @sqlstatement as varchar(1000)= 'insert into  myTabel (name_data1, name_data2, name_data3) VALUES ( @col1, @col2, @col3)'

    declare @parmlist = '@col1 varchar(50) , @col2 varchar(50), @col3 varchar(50)'
    
    exec  sp_executesql
            @sqlstatement 
            ,@parmlist 
            , @col1  = '123'
            , @col2 = NULL
            , @col3 =NULL
```